# Method (correctly) declares variables as 0 but I don't understand why?

Tags: java, methods, zero

I have some code to look at for a class and I understand most of it, but am confused about this method.  With the given code, wouldn't the return change always result in 0 since the last thing put in was that the totalOfItems and the totalGiven are 0.0. I was told that when running it that won't happen but I'd like to understand why.  Can anyone help me?

```
 public SelfCheckout () {
 this.totalOfItems = 0.0;
 this.totalGiven = 0.0;
 }

 /**
  * This method will scan the item.
 * @param amount The amount the items cost.
 */

public void scanItem (double amount){
this.totalOfItems = this.totalOfItems + amount;
}

/** The method will add the items scanned and return the total due.
 * 
 * @return getTotalDue The getTotalDue is the total amount of items scanned.
 */
public double getTotalDue(){
    return this.totalOfItems;
}

/** The method will show the amount that is received from the consumer.
 * 
 */
public void receivePayment(double amount){
    this.totalGiven = this.totalGiven + amount;
}

/**The method will calculate the amount of change due.
 * 
 */
public double produceChange(){
    double change = this.totalGiven - this.totalOfItems;
    this.totalGiven = 0.0;
    this.totalOfItems = 0.0;
    return change;
```

Answer (score 3):

Statements execute in order. Changes to `totalGiven` and `totalOfItems` won't change `change` after it has been computed.

Comment: Right, but since we change totalGiven and totalOfItems to 0 before asking the compiler to return change, wouldn't it return 0?

Comment: @user2769212 `change` isn't a function of two variables it's a constant that is calculated from the value of the variables when it's calculated.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it now.  change is now it's own variable that is equal to the original this.totalGiven - this.totalOfItems;  So, it is okay to reset this.totalGiven and this.totalOfItems without effecting change.  Right?

Comment: @user2769212 Correct.

Answer (score 0):

For this:

```
double change = this.totalGiven - this.totalOfItems;
this.totalGiven = 0.0;
this.totalOfItems = 0.0;
return change;
```

*first* you assign a (non-zero) value to `change`, *then* you reset the original variables, and only then return the value of `change`. The variable values are copied to another variable and then reset.

Comment: I wish I understood what you just said.... I think what you are saying that in the first line, "double change = this.totalGiven - this.totalOfItems;" the "totalGiven" and "totalOfItems" really represent a different totalGiven and totalOfItems.  I thought I'd need to rename them or something, but now that sortof makes some sense.....

Comment: The statements simply execute in order. It's really that simple. `return change;` returns whatever value `change` already has.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption I think is that at some point receivePayment and scanItem have already been called so they reassign the field variables to a number that is not zero. Then change is given. The transaction is closed after you have already computed change you reset the variables for the next transaction.